# Trying to solve an equation without success

Tags: equation-solving

I'm trying to solve the following equation

```
(1-b)(y^(f-1)f)/(1+y^f)-((c+b)(1-a))/(1-y) = 0
```

for y. It looks simple enough, but Solve only gives me a solution where y = 0^(1/(-1-f)), which is not satisfactory. Reduce is not even providing output and just keeps on running for hours. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: What have you tried? Post `Mathematica` code ?

Comment: This might be more tractable if you knew approximate values of `f` and `y`.  Numerical solution for specific values of the parameters would probably relatively simple.